# In Nodejs, how can I do IP rotation for requests that I send? any free proxy service you could recommend?

Tags: proxy, rotation, ip

Is there an npm package to do IP rotation for free?

```
const agent = new HttpsProxyAgent('http://144.49.99.18:8080');
try {
    const response = await fetch('http://httpbin.org/ip', { agent });
    const body = await response.text();
    console.log(body);
} catch (error) {
    //console.log('error', error);
}
```

instead of providing a static IP, how can I get a random IP from a big pool?